# Converting Neural Network output to classes

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

I am working on [document classification problem](https://www.kaggle.com/c/learn-ai-bbc/data) from Kaggle.

It has 5 classes - *'business', 'tech', 'politics', 'sport', 'entertainment'*

I have trained my Deep Learning model and got the results for the test set as well. But the result I am getting is the list of probabilities of different classes.

[Output for one row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKenM.png)

How to get the actual classes(labels) from the output I got?

My Neural Network architecture looks like this-

[Network Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eetDb.png)

Comment: The maximum value of probability corresponds to that label. For eg, if the probability of 4th item is largest, that means the label is 'sport'. Use standard if-else statements to achieve this.

Comment: @AditiSingh, I got it! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should choose the entry with the highest value as the predicted class. For example, in your provided example: `[0.045, 0.030, 0.015, 0.889, 0.019]`, the predicted class is the forth class (i.e., `idx=3`) which has the highest probability value.

The [argmax](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) function of NumPy is probably what you should be using. Considering that `pred` are the output probablities from your network in the shape of: `(batch_size, num_labels)`, then `np.argmax(pred, axis=1)` will give you the indices (i.e., labels) associated with the predicted classes.